# Android Studio. Clickable Progress Bar

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-activity

I have created a progress bar in Android Studio that goes from 100 to 0 with a *step* 10 and *sleep*(500).Each step is displayed.

Now what I want to do is to make the step occur whenever I click on the bar.
How do I do this? 
I wouldn't like to create a button on the backgroud of the progress bar, I would like to be able to click on it and make it wait for my next click.

Thank you!

Comment: set onclick listener on your progress bar and update it everytime a click is registerd

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set

```
android:clickable(true)
android:onClick(something())
```

when you set onClick, you dont need to set a ClickListener